# nginx / sails / SSL - receiving 200 OK before file upload complete

Tags: ssl, nginx, upload, sails.js

When I enable SSL on NGINX, and I upload a file larger than 7MB, the file upload does not complete. This works fine if I remove NGINX and just put the SSL directly onto sails. I get the following from the debug file as if I am receiving a status 200 before the file is complete:

```
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 sendfile: 1899007 of 54230479 @4670513
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 chain writer out: 0000564D9740D5D0
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 event timer: 14, old: 1485260776372, new: 1485260776465
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http upstream request: "/api/v1/project/56cd9e2aeabf5be95d6e9b35/report/?"
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http upstream process header
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 malloc: 0000564D9740F870:4096
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 recv: eof:0, avail:1
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 recv: fd:14 413 of 4096
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http proxy status 200 "200 OK"
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http proxy header: "Vary: X-HTTP-Method-Override"
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http proxy header: "X-Powered-By: Sails <sailsjs.org>"
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http proxy header: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http proxy header: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 posix_memalign: 0000564D97410880:4096 @16
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http proxy header: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http proxy header: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http proxy header: "Access-Control-Expose-Headers: "
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http proxy header: "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http proxy header: "Content-Length: 94"
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http proxy header: "ETag: W/"5e-dbzI0uHc1qmLjPTL2hIz3A""
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http proxy header: "Date: Tue, 24 Jan 2017 12:25:16 GMT"
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http proxy header: "Connection: keep-alive"
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 http proxy header done
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 xslt filter header
2017/01/24 12:25:16 [debug] 2645#2645: *5 HTTP/1.1 200 OK^M
Server: nginx/1.11.8^M
Date: Tue, 24 Jan 2017 12:25:16 GMT^M
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8^M
Content-Length: 94^M
Connection: keep-alive^M
Vary: X-HTTP-Method-Override^M
X-Powered-By: Sails <sailsjs.org>^M
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ^M
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: ^M
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: ^M
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ^M
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ^M
ETag: W/"5e-dbzI0uHc1qmLjPTL2hIz3A"^M
```

Below is my nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {


        sendfile on;
        send_timeout 60s;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 60s;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        client_body_buffer_size 32K;
        ssl_dhparam /ssl/dhparam.pem;
        client_body_in_file_only clean;
        client_body_in_single_buffer on;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;


        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
        }
```

Here is my sites-available\default file:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name mysite.co.uk;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    client_body_buffer_size 32K;

location / {
        client_body_temp_path /tmp/;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        client_body_buffer_size 32K;
        keepalive_timeout 60s;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    ssl_certificate /ssl/mykey.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl/mykey.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:128m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA$
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    ssl_stapling on;
 ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add your NGINX configuration?

Comment: Added my two config files. As said above, it seems to be files sized around 5-7MB when the process doesn't work. This is only when SSL is enabled. If I disable SSL, the process works fine with no limit to how big the file can be. Let me know if you need extracts from any other files.

Comment: @FaisalMemon Have the config files give any indication as to what I could be doing wrong? :)

Comment: The only thing that stands out to me is disabling `ssl_session_tickets` which I don't think is typical. I would try commenting that out and maybe the `ssl_stapling` config and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @FaisalMemon removing these lines does not change the outcome.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. You have lots of optional config (sendfile, client_body_in_single_buffer) so I would suggest to start with the basic NGINX config and add in only the minimum config to proxy to your app without SSL and see if that works.

Comment: @FaisalMemon As  mentioned above, the config works fine without SSL. Even using only NGINX basic config, as soon as I add SSL, the upload fails after 5MB-7MB.